# What's the difference between "巻寿司" (makizushi), "海苔巻き" (norimaki), and "巻物" (makimono)?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, synonyms, food

It seems there are three words for the same Japanese food item, a kind of "sushi in a long roll":

- "巻寿司" (makizushi)
- "海苔巻き" (norimaki)
- "巻物" (makimono)

Are they all identical / synonyms? Do they refer to subtly different things? Are they used in different regions? Are they used by different generations of Japanese?

[Sidenote: At the risk of side-tracking another food question, there only seems to be one word for these in Korean: "김밥" (gimbap).]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The literal meanings of these words are:

- 巻寿司 (まきずし): sushi roll
- 海苔巻き (のりまき): something rolled with [nori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nori), a specific kind of seaweed
- 巻物 (まきもの): something rolled

[海苔巻き](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B5%B7%E8%8B%94%E5%B7%BB%E3%81%8D) usually refers to sushi roll with nori, but depending on the context, it can refer to other kinds of food, including [海苔巻き卵 (のりまきたまご)](http://cookpad.com/recipe/544345) and [海苔巻き煎餅 (のりまきせんべい)](http://www.minatoya.biz/shohin/okaki_senbei/nori/norimaki.html).

Unlike 海苔巻き, I do not think that 巻物 is understood as sushi roll unless it is clear from the context that one is talking about sushi.  As crunchyt wrote, 巻物 can also mean a scroll.

When used to describe kinds of sushi, these three words are almost synonymous, but sushi rolled with something other than nori ([usually egg](http://www.onigiriya.co.jp/products/norimaki.htm)) can be called 巻寿司 or 巻物 but not 海苔巻き.

Comment: I guess laver is のり? Do you mind if I put an edit to those of us who're not so familiar with English seaweed words? I actually think more people know it just as *nori* rather than *laver* anyway. :)

Comment: @Boaz: Thanks for the suggestion!  I rewrote laver to nori and added a link to Wikipedia (not following your suggestion :) ).  I wanted to avoid the word seaweed because it is broader than what nori refers.

Answer (score 4):

**Norimaki & Makizushi** both refer to the rolled up sushi. Makizushi is used more commonly used than Norimaki. INterestingly Google has 2.28M occurrences of *Norimaki* but 4.85M of *Makizushi*.

**Makimono** (lit: rolled up thing) covers rolled sushi but also describes calligraphic scrolls.

From my experience, older people to use the term Makimono, whereas makizushi is very heard. I've never had a conversation where the term "norimaki" came up, and I used to work in a Japanese restaurant with people form Nagoya, so maybe that one is regional.

Searching the usual Japanese resources did not yield any definitive answers.

PS: Inuit have over one hundred words for snow (ref: http://www.mendosa.com/snow.html). So if Korea only has one word, I guess that shows how important a part of Japanese culinary culture sushi is :D Of course Korea rules when it comes to Bulgogi/Yakiniku.

EDIT: Fixed for anthropological accuracy, and to garner an up vote from @Hippietrail

Comment: I can't upvote you until you restrain from spreading the eskimo snow myth. There is "qanuk" and "aniu" and maybe a couple more if you're lucky d-:

Comment: Make sure you read to the end of the linked Inuit list so you get the full effect of it's authenticity!

Comment: LOL. I guess those eskimos guys ate a lot of MacTla because they had nothing else to eat there in Eskimonia.